# Capture the words in double quotes

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, perl

How to capture the words in the double quote to one line as out.txt

```
more input.txt

"OQ -63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie" "OQ -63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie.ear" "OQ- 63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie.xml"
"OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03" "OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03.ear"     "OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03.xml"

more out.txt

OQ -63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie
OQ -63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie.ear
Q-63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie.xml
OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03
OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03.ear
OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03.xml
```

Comment: Is it possible for the double quote to be escaped/backslashed? What output do you expect if there's a non-pair double quote?

Comment: no backslash before the double quota

Comment: non-pair double not replace the double quota

Comment: Note: a double quota is to be allocated twice as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'print for /"([^"]+)"/g' -- input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `grep`, e.g.:

```
grep -o '[^"]\+' input.txt | grep -v '^ *$'
```

Output:

```
OQ -63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie
OQ -63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie.ear
OQ- 63/ECC/UK/JDA/adRedprairie.xml
OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03
OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03.ear
OQ/CZ/Ecomphos/216_06/OM-S03.xml
```